# Custom plugin development for RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I need to implement sequential message processing on multiple consumers, but only one message per time on the queue. I have a lot of queues, but all of them are sequential and I need multiple consumers support for load balancing and redundancy. Anybody can tell whether it is real or not to limit number of unacknowledged message to 1 per queue?

Answer (score 1):

> Anybody can tell whether it is real or not to limit number of unacknowledged message to 1 per queue?

this isn't possible with multiple consumers. you can limit the number of unacknowledged messages using prefetch limit for a single channel, but not across multiple channels / consumers. it is tied to the channel of the consumer, not the queue.

the only way you can achieve this is with a single consumer and a single queue, using prefetch.

even then, you have no guarantee that the messages will arrive in the queue in the correct order.

(this is a fundamental difficulty with distributed systems of any kind, not a rabbitmq limitation)

look at the [Message Sequencer](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageSequence.html) and [Resequencer](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Resequencer.html) patterns to try and put the messages back in order.

but even then, you're going to run into difficulty.

you'll also want to read up on idempotency so you don't re-process a message that has already been processed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure your consumer to consume only X message(s) at time and same for your channel. Take a look at **QOS** or **Consumer Prefetch**

https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html

Here is an example, where multi-consumers will acknoledge only one message and channel allow only one message to be acknoledged (whatever how much consumers a plugged on it)

```
Channel channel = ...;
Consumer consumer1 = ...;
Consumer consumer2 = ...;
channel.basicQos(1, false); // Per consumer limit
channel.basicQos(1, true);  // Per channel limit
channel.basicConsume("my-queue1", false, consumer1);
channel.basicConsume("my-queue2", false, consumer2);
```

Here, a consumer can acknoledge only one message each time, and the channel can only have one unacknoledged message. You didn't mention which language you use so you'll problably have to adapt this example.